# ASP.NET Core: User.Identity Claims are empty depending on where the HTTP requests are being made from?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, microservices, entity

I have two services implemented with ASP.NET Core: AuthService and UserService.

The AuthService returns a JWT token when login is successful. Sometimes, I will have to identify the user through that token.

In my AuthService's startup.cs I have:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddCors();
        services.AddMvc().SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_1);
        services.AddOptions();
        services.AddRouting();

        services.AddAuthentication("ACE_AUTH")
            .AddCookie("ACE_AUTH", options =>
            {
                options.AccessDeniedPath = "/api/Auth/Forbidden";
                //options.LoginPath = "/";
                options.Cookie.Expiration = new TimeSpan(7, 0, 0, 0);
            }); 

        services.Configure<Controllers.Audience>(Configuration.GetSection("Audience"));
    }
```

The method in AuthService which returns the token has the next:

```
[HttpGet("getasync")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> GetAsync(string loginData, string data)
    {
        if (string.Compare(data, "true") == 0)
        {
            var now = DateTime.UtcNow;

            var claims = new Claim[]
            {
                new Claim(JwtRegisteredClaimNames.Sub, loginData),
                new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, loginData),
                new Claim(JwtRegisteredClaimNames.Jti, Guid.NewGuid().ToString()),
                new Claim(JwtRegisteredClaimNames.Iat, now.ToUniversalTime().ToString(), ClaimValueTypes.Integer64)
            };

            var identity = new ClaimsIdentity(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);
            identity.AddClaims(claims);
            ClaimsPrincipal principal = new ClaimsPrincipal(identity);

            (...)
    }
```

And I have a method in AuthService to return the ClaimTypes.Name (so that I can make an HTTP request from UserService with the token in Authorize Header, and receive the user username):

```
[HttpGet("GetAuthenticatedUsername")]
    public IActionResult GetAuthenticatedUsername()
    {

        var claim = User.Identity.Name;

        if (claim == null)
        {
            return Unauthorized();
        }

        return Ok(claim);
    }
```

But my problem is that if I use Postman to make an HTTP request to GetAuthenticatedUsername() with the JWT token in Authorize Header it is going to work and return me the username.

But if I try to make the same thing from a method in UserService, putting the token in an Authorize header, the User.Entity Claims are empty in AuthService and it doesn't return me the username.

That method in UserService:

```
    public async Task<IActionResult> ProfileInfo()
    {
        string authHeader = this.Request.Headers["Authorization"];
        if (authHeader == null)
        {
            return Unauthorized();
        }

        string[] tokens = authHeader.Split(' ');

        string response;
        string baseUrl = "https://localhost:44396/api/auth/GetAuthenticatedUsername";

        using (HttpClient client = new HttpClient())
        {
            //client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new System.Net.Http.Headers.AuthenticationHeaderValue(tokens[0], tokens[1]);
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Authorization", authHeader);

            using (HttpResponseMessage res = await client.GetAsync(baseUrl))
            using (HttpContent content = res.Content)
            {
                response = await content.ReadAsStringAsync();
            }
        }

       (...)
    }
```

What could be the problem? Why are the AuthService's claims empty when making the request from my other service, but not when I'm making a request to that method directly from Postman?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: When you make the request from UserService are you sure that the value of the Authorization Header starts with Bearer?

Comment: Yes. I'm absolutely sure. Even if I uncomment the line "client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization ..." and change "token[0]" for "Bearer" it gives me the same problem.

Comment: This "client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new System.Net.Http.Headers.AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", tokens[1]);" results in the same problem.